# What does the AdvAgg bundler do?

Tags: css-js-aggregation

The description for the AdvAgg bundler says:

> If not checked, the bundler will not split up aggregates.

I know that aggregation is merging files together and I take that splitting isn't the opposite of *aggregation*. What is it, then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is to take advantage of the browser cache. It can also be used to take advantage of the number of parallel connections that the browser can make.

Example:
Front page has a.css and b.css; node 1 has a.css, b.css and c.css. If using one aggregate then the user going from the front page to node 1 would have to download all of the CSS again. By splitting up the aggregate in a smart manner the user will only need to download c.css

Answer (score 1):

Aggregated bundles can be aggregated in groups. For example, let's say there was some CSS you wanted included in the head tag and other CSS that should be included towards the bottom of your page. In this case there might be two aggregate groups.

In AdvAgg I believe the use-case you really want to look at is for JS more so than CSS. In JS you may have a "site-wide" group and a "theme" group and...

You can also have AdvAgg break up the groups by filesize or number of files being aggregated. There are some old browsers (read <= IE6) that have some issues with number of included CSS and number of CSS definitions in a single CSS file... these settings can be used to help with that.

Also, there are some HTTP2 improvements that make file aggregation less necessary for the typical use case (fewer TCP connection === better), but sometimes you would still want to aggregate in order to keep certain files together since they are functionally similar.